# Nepali keyboard layout help in ubuntu

Tags: keyboard-layout, language-support, localization

how to write गर्दै  ni nepali using nepali keyboard ? 
When i type **gr/d{** it shows **गर्दई** but i want **गर्दै**. Please guys help me to find out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Install the *ibus-m17n* package, log out and log in again. Then, if you go to **System Settings -> Text Entry** you should see two new Nepali options. Hopefully one of those is what you are after.